# Attached Property - "Cannot find the Style Property .. on the type .."

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, attached-properties

I'm currently trying to define an attached property consumable by objects within a usercontrol.

The attached property is registered in the code-behind of said control:

```
public partial class MapEditor : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LatitudeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Latitude", typeof(double), typeof(MapEditor));

    //...
 }
```

I then attempt to bind to these properties in an itemscontrol:

```
<UserControl xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:TestProject.Controls" 
             ...>
    <Grid>
         ...
         <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding Items}>
             <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Controls:MapEditor.Latitude"
                            Value="1" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
         </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

However I am presented with the following error:

```
Error   6   Cannot find the Style Property 'Latitude' on the type 'TestProject.Controls.PhaseEditor'
```

Is there any solution to this? I tried defining the attached properties in a separate class file altogether but the same problem still persists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the answer to this problem.

It seems that it was necessary to declare public static getters and setters for the dependency properties. That is,

```
public static double GetLatitude(DependencyObject obj);
public static void SetLatitude(DependencyObject obj, double value);
```

I believe this need is mentioned somewhere inside the documentation, although I humbly think that it is weird for such a necessity to not be immediately obvious to a user.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day! It seems like when trying to use attached properties and set the via styles (`Name="propertyname" Value="propertyvalue"` hope you know what I mean) it works without these static setters and getters, however, it doesnt when used directly in the normal xaml.